# Can't initialize Room DB inside my Activity

Tags: java, android, android-room

I have a database :

```
@Database(entities = {Bas.class, Cit.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class DB extends RoomDatabase {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "db";

    private static DB Database;



    public static DB getDatabase(Context context){

        if (Database == null){
            Database = Room.databaseBuilder(context, Database.class, DB_NAME)

                    .build();
        }

        return Database;





    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed

```
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:VERSION"
```

to

```
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:VERSION"
```

and resolved it

Answer (score 2):

Modify DB class

> use **synchronized** keyword

```
private static DB sInstance;

public static DB getDatabase(final Context context) {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        synchronized (DB.class) {
            if (sInstance == null) {
                sInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(context, DB.class, DB_NAME)
                        .build();
            }
        }
    }
    return sInstance;
}
```

And initialize db in activity:

```
DB db = DB.getDatabase(getApplicationContext());
```

> Don't forget to define the room dependencies in app.gradle:

```
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:LatestVersion"

annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:LatestVersion"
```